# NSXMLParser Cache

Tags: ios, caching

I'm developing an application that uses the xml parsing. Everything works wing perfection but when I edit the xml file changes are not displayed. I think it may be a matter of cache because the file is loaded correctly on the server. how do I fix it?

```
-(IBAction)avviaParsing{


 NSString *urlstring=@"http://www.acicastelloonline.it/app_ios/show.xml";
    NSURL *xmlURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];  

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[ NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    [parser setDelegate:self];

    [parser parse];

        [parser release];}
```

Comment: Please, please, please don't ship code like this. Loading data from remote URLs on the main thread will block your app's UI, potentially for quite a long time. Use `NSURLConnection` to load asynchronously instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is three option, you should try this code before XMLParsing:

you select only one of the three.

### **clearing**

`[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`

---

### **disable cache**

```
NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil]; 
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache]; 
[sharedCache release];
```

---

### this is other solution.

```
NSURL *xmlURL=[NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:xmlURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:0.0f];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser =[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: -(IBAction)avviaParsing{
    NSString *urlstring=@"http://www.acicastelloonline.it/app_ios/show.xml";
    NSURL *xmlURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]; 
    NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
    [cache release];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[ NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
 [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
     [parser release];
}
always displays the old data

Comment: I pasted this string [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]; before creating the url and in any case do not see the new data ... I also double-checked the xml file on the server and is loaded correctly

Comment: I do not understand where wrong ... the code is executed but still does not clean the cache ... there are no other solutions?